# Nested Tables - cells have incorrect width

Tags: html, css

I have multi-tier nested tables that I am losing the format on the width of the cells even though the width of the cells have been specified in the css:

[image: bad format]

```
<tr>
  <td class="dd">
    3
  </td>
  <td>
    testing the tiering xyxy 
  </td>
  <td class="w-200">
    Practice
  </td>
  <td class="col-yesno">
    Yes
  </td>
  <td class="col-action">
    action
  </td>
</tr>


.dd {
  width:34px
}    
.w-200 {
  width:200px;
}
.col-yesno {
  width:95px
}
.col-action {
  width:160px;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw5zrgxL/24/)

I apologize for all the misc class names and css that are irrelevant to the issue mentioned, but I kept them for better visualization.

Important: i know removing 'table-layout: fixed' fixes the problem, but I am not not allowed to remove that unfortunately

Comment: Is there something forcing you to construct your tables like this? Or beyond your control?

Comment: yes, using a jQuery sorting library for multi-tier sorting: https://www.screencast.com/t/mCwsCgbO9w9